# Read data from h5 file

Tags: keras

Downloaded vgg16_weights from [here](https://keras.io/applications/). I want to save param_0 of layer_1  as numpy array. I am using following code:

```
with h5py.File('vgg16_weights.h5', 'r') as f:
    my_array = f['layer_1/param_0']
```

When i write print(my_array), output is: `Closed HDF5 dataset` and nothing is showing. how to get desired array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `my_array` is not the actual data, but a file pointer to the dataset (similar to `p` in `p=open(filename,'r')`).

You have two options:

a) keep you file open

```
with h5py.File('vgg16_weights.h5', 'r') as f:
    my_array = f['layer_1/param_0']
    print(my_array)
```

b) read the data into an array:

```
with h5py.File('vgg16_weights.h5', 'r') as f:
    my_array = f['layer_1/param_0']
    actual_array = my_array[:]
print(actual_array)
```

The `[:]` tells the h5 file to read all the data into the new variable. Once in your variable you can use it as a regular variable